# How to debug background asset extension in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, background-assets-framework

how to debug the background assets extension using break points?
The app successfully runs at extension's scheme. and tried to run the following command in terminal as described in wwdc 2023

`xcrun backgroundassets-debug --simulate --app-install -d xxxxxxxxxx -b xxx.xxxxx.xxx`

Comment: I’m sure you’ve seen it, but for the sake of future readers, here is the WWDC 2023 introduction to debugging about 29:29 into the [What’s new in Background Assets](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10108?time=1769) video.